# C# TcpClient Send method takes too long sometimes

Tags: c#

If I'm sending data too fast the .Send method takes really long. I'm talking up to 20 ms here, which is not an option for my application. What causes this? And how can I avoid it?

Some test code that reproduces the problem:
test client:

```
            var lol = new TcpClient();
        lol.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("123.123.123.123"), 1234);

        while (true)
        {
            var watchy = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            lol.Client.Send(new byte[] {123, 34, 34, 98, 45, 87, 34, 78, 45, 76, 45, 23, 154, 146, 1, 1, 1, 11, 66}); // random test data
            watchy.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(watchy.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

            if (watchy.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 1)
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

test server:

```
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        listener.Start();
        var clients = new List<TcpClient>();

        while (true)
        {
            if (listener.Pending())
            {
                clients.Add(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                Console.WriteLine("client connected!");
            }

            foreach (var tcpClient in clients)
            {
                var data = new byte[tcpClient.Available];
                tcpClient.Client.Receive(data);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", data));
            }
        }
```

I think the receiver can't process the data fast enough. But how can I check if I'm currerntly able to send data without the delay? I'm sending to multiple clients, which means that other clients will experience lag because one client wasn't able to process the data fast enough

Comment: Can you show some of your code?  You'll likely have to switch it to asynchronous.

Comment: Hard to tell. Are You sure the receiver can process the data faster than you can send it? Or the connection is lousy and you loose packets on the way which causes dup acks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the connection isn't lousy, because if I send the packets slower, I don't have the problem. I think the receiver can't process the data fast enough. But how can I check if I'm currerntly able to send data without the delay? I'm sending to multiple clients, which means that other clients will experience lag because one client wasn't able to process the data fast enough

Comment: If latency is what you're after, start by setting [`TcpClient.NoDelay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay.aspx) to `true`.

Comment: The speed depends on a lot of factors.  You could have virus checks looking a the contents of the file.  If you are on a corporate network group policies may require authentication.  I would test the code with a null modem cable between two computers that are located near each other to determine if there are issue with the software bypassing the network to determine where the issue is located.   You may just have a bad Ethernet cable or hub/router.  Performing pings between different computers and checking response times may also help isolate where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Are you connecting to remote machines? If yes you can check with a network analyzer like Wireshark what is going on. With what speed are you sending? 100 MBit/s or much less? You can check with Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by setting .Blocking of the socket to false